# Java webapp media directory

Tags: java, image, http, glassfish

I'm working on a Java EE project that provide a servlet that store a lot of images (or common files) into glassfish server for specific users.
I'm wondering if there are standard directories to save the files into standard web programming.

For example, I have three users that want upload their files, where I can save them into server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are'nt any standard directories. I suggest you to create directory on a server to each user. For example: The user registers, some data goes to the database and also a directory for this user is created. Than this user can upload any file to his own directory.

P.S you can create directories anywhere on the server, then configure the path of directory in  server's JNDI resources for look in your application.

You have to create `PropertiesObjectFactory` class to handle JNDI properties of java.util.Porperties (if you are using glassfish 2). Or yuo can write your custom ObjectFactory also. Glassfish 3 already have this function. It is set into: org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory.

1. Create directory somewhere on the server. For e.g: /server/glassfish/users
2. Open glassfish admin console and navigate to: Resources -> JNDI -> Custom Resources, click "New". Provide a JNDI name, for e.g: jndi/users_directories, choose a resource type "`java.util.Properties`", specify Factory class: `org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory`, then click "Add property", specify name for e.g: `users.directories` and in value column copy your directory path. In this case: `/server/glassfish/users`. Click OK and thats all.
3. Restart application server.
4. Make a look up in your application:

`public Properties getProperties(String jndiName) {
        Properties properties = null;
        try {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            properties = (Properties) context.lookup(jndiName);
            context.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Naming error occurred while initializing properties from JNDI.", e);
            return null;
        }
        return properties;
    }`

When you call this method in your application provide a JNDI name you configured in your application server`: jndi/users_directories`. If you have mapped resources in deploymet descriptor you have to use: java:comp/env/jndi/users_directories.

If you whant to do the same using spring:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="usersDirectories"
                 jndi-name="jndi/users_directories"/>
```

Or if you are using glassfish 2, then create a custom PropertiesObjectFactory class:

```
public class PropertiesObjectFactory implements Serializable, ObjectFactory {

    /**
     * File property name.
     */
    public static final String FILE_PROPERTY_NAME = "org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory.fileName";

    /**
     * Implemented method from object factory interface.
     *
     * @param obj object
     * @param name name
     * @param nameCtx context name
     * @param environment environment
     * @return file properties
     * @throws Exception if error occurs
     */
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable<?, ?> environment)
            throws Exception {
        Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
        Enumeration<RefAddr> refAddrs = ref.getAll();

        String fileName = null;
        Properties fileProperties = new Properties();
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        while (refAddrs.hasMoreElements()) {
            RefAddr addr = refAddrs.nextElement();
            String type = addr.getType();
            String value = (String) addr.getContent();

            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(FILE_PROPERTY_NAME)) {
                fileName = value;
            } else {
                properties.put(type, value);
            }
        }

        if (fileName != null) {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (!file.isAbsolute()) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("com.sun.aas.installRoot") + File.separator + fileName);
            }
            try {
                if (file.exists()) {
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                        if (fileName.toUpperCase().endsWith("XML")) {
                            fileProperties.loadFromXML(fis);
                        } else {
                            fileProperties.load(fis);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        throw new IOException("IO Exception during properties load : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        fileProperties.putAll(properties);
        return fileProperties;
    }
}
```

Make a .jar file of this class and put it to server global library directory. Provide this factory class for your JNDI resources, restart the server and you are good to use the same look up, covered above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've read also about alternate doc root, and I'm trying to configure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224887/problems-with-glassfish-web-xml but doesn't work. Now, I try with your solution. Can you provide me some examples or tutorial to understand quickly JNDI functions?

Comment: Sorry, last question. If the user want to display his file from browser (with http:// url), how I can provide an href link?

Comment: You mean his file's content, or a download link? If a download link you need to write some sort of class to handle file download. For e.g. FileDownloadServlet. Then make an call to this servlet by specifying the file name, not a directory, directory you already have looked up from JNDI. There a plenty of examples how to download file from server using java, there is one: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4629.

You can also find full tutorials how to make an application of downloading some files.

Comment: Thanks, but I would only provide a url (e.g. http://www.mysite/image.jpg) that map  /server/glassfish/users/image.jsp. There is a way to do it?

Comment: I am sure there is but I do not know the solution for this at the moment, sorry.